# Ionic Angular 2 - Return Observable from Nested Promises

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, promise, observable

I have function in which I want to return an Observable as my query result. I am making a SQLite Query and I want to return the result in an Observable. I tried putting the Observable.of outside at the first Promise function but it did not work. This is my code.

```
GetCustomers(FilterOptions: any): Observable<any> { 

            return Observable.of(this.platform.ready().then(() => { //WRONG CODE

                 this.SQLObj.executeSql("select * from customers, {}).then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                });

            })).map(cust => {
                // MODIFY THE RESULT AND CREATE NEW OBJECT.
                return JSON.stringify(cust);
            })

        }
```

Basically I want to return an Observable with nested promises but before that I want to modify and customize the resulted data of the SQL Query. What is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work as you want.

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.platform.ready())
.switchMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.SQLObj.executeSql("select * from customers", {})))
.map((cust) => JSON.stringify(cust));
```